# Can window tint affect smart entry?

Tags: honda, accord, smartkey, tint

Can window tinting process affect the [smart entry feature](https://salestraining.honda.com/en/Accord-Family/2018-Accord/Product-Details/Exterior/Smart-Entry-and-Push-Button-Start-EX-and-EX-L-Navi) of a car ?

*Smart entry allows one to lock/unlock the door without taking the key fob from the pocket. Typically, If i have the key fob in my pocket, I can just grab the handle and it will unlock the car. Similarly, I can press the black button in the handle to to lock the doors.*

I did window tinting on my Honda Accord 2013 sedan, at a reputed local shop few days ago and when I picked up the car I noticed the smart entry indicator stays on all the time. Also the smart entry is not working when I want to open/close the door ( I have to explicitly click on the open/close door button in key fob). When I asked the tint guys, they said it is because they kept the doors opened for a long time to do the tint job and wait a week.

Today is the 7th day since this happened. It does not work for driver door, passenger door and trunk! The batteries in my key fob are relatively new. Usually I get a sign about low battery in key fob when the battery is low.

Reached out to the tint shop and this is their response

> Scott, our Tint Manager, observed that most frequently the cause of
>   the smart key problem you are experiencing is a low battery in the key
>   fob. Let us know status after you replace the battery.
>
> On the other hand, in rare cases some moisture temporarily compromised
>   the electronic controls and with time, usually with in 3 to 5 days,
>   evaporation solved the problem.

Has anyone experienced this ? What is the reasoning behind it goes away after few days ?Electronics usually die when some short circuit happens, is my understanding.

I tried resetting the power by disconnect and reconnecting the batter 3 days ago. Did not help!

It is nano ceramic tint, not metallic if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the "moisture" is actually the solvent in the adhesive, not water, and it is electrically conductive, so it blocks the radio signal from your key fob.

The signal can only be transmitted through the windows, because the metal of the car body will block it.

Test if you can lock and unlock the doors with a window open.

Comment: Aren't most tints applied to the inner window surface by wetting the window or film? The tints on mine are coming off in parts and there is no adhesive...

Comment: @SolarMike typically, they’d use soapy water to get the film in place and activate the adhesive on the fil, and squeegee the film to remove the water.

Comment: @3Dave so, the4 tint is coming off some of my windows and there is no adhesive... it peels off lightly...

Comment: @SolarMike There are different kinds. Some have a light adhesive on the back of the film, others are "static cling."